# Do SIMD construct of openMP require a particular kind of hardware?

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp, vectorization, hardware

https://bisqwit.iki.fi/story/howto/openmp/

> The simd construct (OpenMP 4.0+) OpenMP 4.0 added explicit SIMD
>   parallelism (Single-Instruction, Multiple-Data). SIMD means that
>   multiple calculations will be performed simultaneously by the
>   processor, using special instructions that perform the same
>   calculation to multiple values at once. This is often more efficient
>   than regular instructions that operate on single data values. This is
>   also sometimes called vector parallelism or vector operations (and is
>   in fact the preferred term in OpenACC).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD

> Single instruction, multiple data (SIMD), is a class of parallel computers in Flynn's taxonomy.

Do SIMD construct of openMP require a particular kind of hardware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [OpenMP Specification (p. 8)](http://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/openmp-4.5.pdf):

> - SIMD instruction: A single machine instruction that can operate on
>     multiple data elements.
> - SIMD lane: A software or hardware mechanism
>     capable  of processing one data element from a SIMD instruction .
> - SIMD chunk: A set of iterations executed concurrently, each by a  SIMD
>     lane , by a single thread by means of  SIMD instructions.
> - SIMD loop: A loop that includes at least one SIMD chunk.

The short answer is **Yes**.
In Detail this is as Mats Peterson states e.g. SSE, AVX, Neon or AltiVec.

The special hardware need results from the description of SIMD lane. However, the underlying technology is not specified and therefore is implementation-dependent (on runtime library). So there might be more or less technologies supported.

Also note that OpenMP statements are ignored if the requirements are not fulfilled. So if you intruduce the statement in your code and the target hardware does not support SIMD instructions no error occurs.

Answer (score 3):

## No.

The OpenMP `simd` **construct** does **not** require a particular kind of hardware. The **construct** merely indicates that a loop ***can** be transformed into a SIMD loop* (as per [Specification 2.8.1](http://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/openmp-4.5.pdf)). It is a hint to the compiler, it does not require the compiler to transform it to SIMD instructions.

Actual *SIMD loop*s do require hardware support as detailed by the other answers.

Comment: This is the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. As per the quoted text in the original question:

> using special instructions that perform the same calculation to
>   multiple values at once.

This requires that the processor has such instructions, which is part of the hardware design to implement those instructions. That would be SSE or AVX on x86 processors, AltiVec on PowerPC and Neon on ARM.